# Raspberry pi access-point routing not working

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, iptables, access-point

I have setup an access point on my raspberry pi 4 following this guide:
https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#before-you-begin

I can connect to the wireless network, ping the ip address on the raspberry pi wlan interface, and dns seems to work fine.
[image]

[image]

But the NAT/routing is not working. I'm unable to access the internet or the rest of my network.
[image]

I believe this has something to do with docker and maybe messing up my iptables? But I don't know enough about iptables to explain why it isn't working. This is a dump of the iptables.
I see the rule "-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE" was added which should enable the nat routing for my access-point.

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Feb 26 12:27:58 2023
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [36647:6241476]
:FORWARD DROP [151:15122]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [34684:33197826]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-ea8912f60ffe -o br-ea8912f60ffe -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.3/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9443 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.3/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.4/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p udp -m udp --dport 10001 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.3/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.4/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.4/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.4/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p udp -m udp --dport 3478 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 ! -s 172.80.0.0/24 -o br-ea8912f60ffe -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 ! -d 172.80.0.0/24 -i br-ea8912f60ffe -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Feb 26 12:27:58 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Feb 26 12:27:58 2023
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1508:237688]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1207:192448]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [15971:766826]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [8642:433956]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.2/32 -d 172.17.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9443 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.2/32 -d 172.17.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.3/32 -d 172.17.0.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.2/32 -d 172.17.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8000 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.3/32 -d 172.17.0.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.4/32 -d 172.17.0.4/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 10001 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.4/32 -d 172.17.0.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.4/32 -d 172.17.0.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.4/32 -d 172.17.0.4/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 3478 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.2/32 -d 172.17.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.3/32 -d 172.17.0.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9443 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.2/32 -d 172.17.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.3/32 -d 172.17.0.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.3/32 -d 172.17.0.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8000 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:443
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9443 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.3:9443
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:80
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.3:9000
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p udp -m udp --dport 10001 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.4:10001
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.3:8000
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.4:8443
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.4:8080
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p udp -m udp --dport 3478 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.4:3478
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Feb 26 12:27:58 2023
```

I tried adding a specific rule for the subnet I'm trying to route with

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.4.0/24 ! -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I also tried cleaning the ip tables with sudo iptables -F , but docker seems to immediately change the file again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to allow forwarding of traffic from the wlan interface to the eth interface and you will also need to allow reverse traffic for established connections. Something like this should work:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: You are completely right, thank you, it works perfectly now!